# Extra data from an array

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, echo

I have create this array:

```
 $studentAssProg[]=array('studentID'=> $studentID,'assignmentID'=>$assignmentID,'assProgLevel'=>$progress);
```

what would be the best way to print the progressLevel, for each student where assignmentID = '3' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($studentAssProg as $data){
    if($data['assignmentID']==3){
         echo $data['assProgLevel'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($studentAssProg as $d) : 
    if($d['assignmentID'] == 3)
        echo $d['assProgLevel'];
endforeach;
```